# How can a cemetery be Tahor?

Tags: halacha-theory, tamei-tahor-ritual-purity, cemetery-grave

In the [Kitzur Shulchan Aruch in 128:13](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Kitzur_Shulchan_Aruch.128.13?lang=bi&with=Tanakh&lang2=en) he states, regarding going to a cemetery on Erev Rosh Hashana:

> וְגַם מֵחֲמַת שֶׁהוּא מְקוֹם קְבוּרַת הַצַּדִּיקִים, הַמָּקוֹם הוּא קָדוֹשׁ וְ**טָהוֹר**, וְהַתְּפִלָּה מְקֻבֶּלֶת שָׁם בְּיוֹתֵר, בִּהְיוֹתָהּ עַל אַדְמַת קֹדֶשׁ, וְיַעֲשֶׂה הַקָּדוֹשׁ בָּרוּךְ הוּא חֶסֶד בִּזְכוּת הַצַּדִּיקִים‏
>
> An additional reason for going to the cemetery is that the place where tzaddikim are buried is sacred and **pure**, and prayers are more readily accepted when they are offered on sacred ground, and the Holy One, blessed is He, will show us kindness for the sake of the tzaddikim.

The definition of Kadosh - קָדוֹשׁ - is tricky and seems to be related to *how much connection the place has to Hashem*. (But I'm open to other explanations.)

The definition of Tahor - טָהוֹר - is well defined. It's a place that has been purified from various types of Tum'a. One of the most serious types of Tum'a (and in some aspect, The most serious type) is the Tum'a caused by corpses.

Cemeteries are inherently not Tahor and a Cohen is not even allowed to come close to the graves because of this.

The same wording is used by the [Kaf HaChaim O"C 581:95](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Kaf_HaChayim_on_Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.581.95.1?vhe=Kaf_Hachayim,_Orach_Chayim_vol._V-VIII,_Jerusalem_1910-1933&lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) and the [Ba'er Hetev, O"C 581:15](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Ba'er_Hetev_on_Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.581.17?vhe=Torat_Emet_357&lang=bi&with=Halakhah&lang2=en) which refers to [S"A O'C 581:4](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.581.4?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) which says:

> מכבסין ומסתפרין בערב ראש השנה (ויש נוהגין לטבול בערב ר"ה משום קרי) (כל בו) (**ויש מקומות נוהגין לילך על הקברות ולהרבות שם בתחינות** (מהרי"ל) ונותנים שם צדקה לעניים (כל בו):‏
>
> One bathes and cuts their hair on the eve of Rosh Hashana. (and there are those that are accustomed to immerse in a mikvah on the eve of Rosh Hashana on account of seminal emission). (**And there are places where there is a custom to go to the graves and to pray there** and to give charity to poor people there.)

#### How can one refer to a cemetery as a *Pure* place - a מָּקוֹם טָהוֹר?

Where did this phrase come from that so many Seforim use it?

Note the [Mishna Berura 581:27](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Mishnah_Berurah.581.28?vhe=On_Your_Way&lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) skips the Kadosh and Tahor part.

> (כז) הקברות - דביה"ק הוא **מקום מנוחת הצדיקים** והתפלה נתקבלה שם יותר אך אל ישים מגמתו נגד המתים אך יבקש מהש"י שיתן עליו רחמים בזכות הצדיקים שוכני עפר ויקיף הקברות ויתן צדקה קודם שיאמר התחנות. ואין לילך על קבר אחד ב"פ ביום אחד:‏

Comment: קברי צדיקים אינם מטמאים?

Comment: While I admire your fidelity to original meanings, is it really so uncommon to find Tahor used outside its technical context? How many Chasidim dunk in drawn water to add "levels of tahara" whatever that means?

Comment: @DoubleAA - Either they are confusing Kedusha with Tahara, or else they have the answer. Where else - in classic texts - do we find Tahara unrelated to Tum'a?

Comment: Who said anything about classic texts?? You're quoting a text that's barely 150 years old

Comment: @JoelK - 9 קיצור שלחן ערוך ר״ב:י״ד: יש כהנים הדיוטים נוהגים ללכת על קברי צדיקים, באמרם שקברי הצדיקים אינם מטמאים, וטעות הוא בידיהם וצריכין למחות להם - I know of no other instance of this mentioned in Halacha. Nor does Sefaria. :-)

Comment: @DannySchoemann http://olamot.net/shiur/%D7%9B%D7%94%D7%A0%D7%99%D7%9D-%D7%91%D7%A7%D7%91%D7%A8%D7%99-%D7%A6%D7%93%D7%99%D7%A7%D7%99%D7%9D

Comment: In Hebrew, it's just an idiom, as two words are so frequently used in pair. I use a simple test for that - is that word you question מעניין of the subject or not. As the טהור is a description of the Tzaddikim and not the Halachic issue, it should not be taken seriously, but as an idiom. If the subject was "eating Kodshim at a cemetry" and the word טהור was used, you would have a valid question.

Comment: @AlBerko - we spend so much time being מדקדק on every word the Poskim use, and inferring "new" Halachot from minor variances, and now you tell me that this is merely an idiom. That's perplexing.

Comment: No, this is exactly what I'm trying to differentiate in the first place - when the Poskim are מדקדקים and when they just use "figure of speech". So that's my personal test - only when the word is מן העניין it can be researched, but when it's not - it's just a figure of speech and can not be taken seriously. I do agree though that you might say Drashos on everything, but I'm very cautious to introduce NEW HALOCHOS based on those "inconsistencies".

Comment: I also remind you, that Judaism did not decide on a fixed set of terminology to be used in Psakim, therefore the uses vary so much and also can not be מדקדק. The words קדוש and טהור are good examples of such terms we have no agreed meaning of.

Comment: Another test is the Poysek's weight, we would treat Tana's words [a bit] differently than 19th century kitzur s"a

Comment: @AlBerko: _ The words קדוש and טהור are good examples of such terms we have no agreed meaning of._ - You're kidding me, right? The word Tahor is very well defined. (Or, used to be.)

Comment: I'm not kidding, the more you read the more you see the vagueness of those terms. Try to define אסור for example, albeit every kid understands the concept in general, it is very hard to come to a consensus on the exact definition.